# How to detect single Tap on WebView

Tags: android, onclick, android-webview

How to detect single Tap on the `WebView`. I am displaying `WebView` as a `ViewPager` page. So, I can't use `OnTouchListener`. And `OnClickListener` doesn't work on `WebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a link to get the event you can use something like this with shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    String host = null;
                    if (null != url && null != (host = Uri.parse(url).getHost())) {
                        if (host.equals("myclikableUrl")) {
                            clickEvent();
                        } 

                        return true;
                    } else {

                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }.....
});
```

Comment: Nope, I don't have any links in the `WebView`. I want to detect tap on the whole `WebView`

Comment: I don't know your view hierarchy but can't you set an onClickListener on child view of ViewPager?(I am guessing childViews are webpages?)  It may work.

Comment: I have a ViewPager, in which few pages are WebViews. I want to detect single Tap (OR Click) on WebViews. If I handle Touch on WebView, it doesn't allow me swipe the ViewPager pages. OnClickListsner doesn't work. Also, the WebView is scrollable Horizontally & Verically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to crete your own class that extends `WebView` and here override `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`. Also you could add `GestureDetector` and catch single tap on webview http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html