# Detect Single Tap on webview

Tags: android, webview, gesture-recognition

i am using motion events with webview so i cant directly use on touchlistener

i am using the following way

```
package com.example.webviewdemo;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private long touchDownMs;
private Handler handler;
private int numberOfTaps;
private long lastTapTimeMs;


public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}
public void newTouch(){

}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      handler= new Handler();
     if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
     {
         return true;
     }



      if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

          touchDownMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
          return v.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
     else if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

          handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

          if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - touchDownMs) > ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()) {
              //it was not a tap

              numberOfTaps = 0;
              lastTapTimeMs = 0;

          }

          if (numberOfTaps > 0 
                  && (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTimeMs) < ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout()) {
              numberOfTaps += 1;
          } else {
              numberOfTaps = 1;
          }

          lastTapTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

          if (numberOfTaps == 3) {
 //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "triple", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //handle triple tap
          } else if (numberOfTaps == 2) {
              handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      //handle double tap
                      newTouch();
//                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "double", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              }, ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout());
          }
          return v.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
          else{
              return v.onTouchEvent(event);
             }


 }

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


}
```

implementation on my webview

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeLeft() {
                            // Whatever


                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeRight() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        }
                        @Override
                        public void newTouch() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    });
```

i can get double taps and triple taps from this but i only need one complete tap not just ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN  but both together within milliseconds gap .
if in my code i write numberOfTaps ==1   then it is detecting  Action_Down  not complete tap. I need to get complete 1 tap detecting.
 thanks in advance

i already saw [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565930/android-cant-detect-single-tap) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022384/how-to-detect-single-tap-on-webview) but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.webviewdemo;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
private static final int MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE = 15;
static Context mcontext;
private long pressStartTime;
private float pressedX;
private float pressedY;
private boolean stayedWithinClickDistance;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    this.mcontext=context;
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}
public void newTouch(){

}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

     if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
     {
          if (stayedWithinClickDistance && distance(pressedX, pressedY, event.getX(), event.getY()) > MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE) {
              stayedWithinClickDistance = false;
          }
         return true;
     }

     else if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                
         pressedX = event.getX();
         pressedY = event.getY();
         stayedWithinClickDistance = true;

         return v.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
     else if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

         long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressStartTime;
         if (pressDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION && stayedWithinClickDistance) {
            newTouch();
         }

         return v.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
     else{
         return v.onTouchEvent(event);
     }

}
private static float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float dx = x1 - x2;
    float dy = y1 - y2;
    float distanceInPx = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return pxToDp(distanceInPx);
}

private static float pxToDp(float px) {
    return px / mcontext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}


private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


}
```

solved it using this  [How to distinguish between move and click in onTouchEvent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965695/how-to-distinguish-between-move-and-click-in-ontouchevent?rq=1)